# My cumulative distribution function is giving values twice as large as they should be

Tags: python

I was trying to code a function python to calculate the cumulative distribution function of a continuous variable.

My initial code looked like this:

```
def cdf_t(d):
    t = ((np.exp(-(0.08*((d*1.2)-60))-1))-1.1)/0.5
    def integrand(x):
        return np.exp((-x**2)/2)
    result = 1.0-((1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*(quad(integrand,-np.inf,t)[0]))
    return result
```

but gave a plot that looked like this

[image]

I realized the error was due to the limits of scipy's integrate.quad function, so I split the integral into two parts.

My new code looks like this:

```
def cdf_t(d):
    t = ((np.exp(-(0.08*((d*1.2)-60))-1))-1.1)/0.5
    def integrand(x):
        return np.exp((-x**2)/2)
    if d<10:
        return 1-((1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*(quad(integrand,-np.inf,t)[0]))
    else:
        integral_left = 1-((1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*(quad(integrand,-np.inf,35)[0]))
        integral_right = 1-((1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*(quad(integrand,35,t)[0]))
        return integral_left+integral_right
```

and gives a plot like this

[image]

It fixed the calculation error, but now the bounds of my plot are from 1 to 2, instead 0 to 1, as they should be. Running values one by one through the function shows that it's producing integrals twice as large as they should be.

I tried playing around with the bounds of my integrals, but it either didn't change anything or gave me a broken backwards function.

I know python has built in functions for calculating cdf, but they're too limited for what I need to with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is: *quad can't integrate `∫_-∞^t f(x)dx` correctly, so, let's (for reason you seem to understand and that seems to be validated by your result), compute `∫_-∞^A f(x)dx` and `∫_A^t f(x)dx` instead, and sum both, to have `∫_-∞^t f(x)dx`.*

That seems right. But that is not what your are doing.

What you are doing is
computing `1 - ∫_-∞^A f(x)dx`
computing `1 - ∫_A^t f(x)dx`
sum both to get `2 - ∫_-∞^t f(x)dx`

Which is then, naturally, 1 more that what you wanted.

So, if I am correct, mitigation is: just remove 1 from the result.
Or  let `integal_left` and `integral_right` be really the left and right integral, and then return `1-integral_left-integral_right`